# Why doesn't this iOS project build using XCode 11?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have an iphone app (Swift project) that used to build using an older version of XCode, but I haven't built it for a year (I updated my XCode) and now I can't build it. I tried everything I found after googling the problem. I get this error every time I try to build it:

`unable to spawn process (No such file or directory) (in target 'CombineDataSources' from project 'Pods')`

I don't get any other error when I try to build the project, just this one.
I tried cleaning the build folder, deleting all pods (Library/Cashes/CocoaPods/Pods), deleting derived data (Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData), deleting the xcworkspace file, then running pod deintegrate command in terminal, then running pod install command in terminal.

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing CombineDataSources (0.2.2)
...
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 14 dependencies from the Podfile and 20 total pods installed.
```

Podfile (part that contains the package that's part of the Xcode error):

`pod 'CombineDataSources', '~> 0.2.2'`

Podfile.lock (part that contains the package that's part of the Xcode error):

```
PODS:
- CombineDataSources (0.2.2)

DEPENDENCIES:
- CombineDataSources (~> 0.2.2)

SPEC REPOS:
trunk:
- CombineDataSources

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
CombineDataSources: 2315365365i8746865375
```

All pods were successfully installed, no errors, no warnings, but my project still gives the unable to spawn process error. Anyone has any idea what else I could try? Any help, any suggestion would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Check 'CombineDataSources' target out, whether it depends on something which location has been changed. [Something like this](https://github.com/ish-app/ish/issues/367)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried to check it.
However, I think if I'm using cocoapods I don't need to worry about which packages the packages I'm using depend on:
"CocoaPods will resolve dependencies between libraries, fetch the resulting source code, then link it together in an Xcode workspace to build your project."
I couldn't even find which packages CombineDataSources depends on.
The developer in the link you attached is using npm.
By the way I've already tried everything they mention in this article, they didn't help :/

Comment: Remove version reference 0.2.2 from pod 'CombineDataSources', '~> 0.2.2', use simple pod 'CombineDataSources', then pod install. See if solves your problem.

Comment: thank you @ares777, but it didn't help :/ I get the same error

Comment: Someone told 

Open 'File -> Workspace Settings' and set Build System to Legacy Build System. I think now you have new build system selected

Comment: thank you @ares777, but I've already tried changing to Legacy Build System :/

Comment: I also have a gemfile in the project folder. Do I need to run any command in the terminal because of this gemfile before I build? I haven't ran anything... just the pod install. (the CombineDataSources isn't in the gemfile)

Comment: Try to clear cocoapods caches 1) delete ~/Library/Caches/Cocoapods 2) pod deintegrate  in your project 3) restart your mac 4) pod install in your project. Sometime it helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot manage to find the spec 0.2.2 in neither the CombineDataSources nor in the specs repo;

The 0.2.2 release seems that doesn't contain the podspec.

In repo not found: https://github.com/CombineCommunity/CombineDataSources/tree/0.2.2

In cocoapod specs not found:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/search?q=combinedatasources&unscoped_q=combinedatasources

Only the latest version seems to contain a podspec. (0.2.5)

Could you try with to `pod install` or `bundle exec pod install` with that version?

Comment: thank you @Ricowere, it fixed it :)
so pod without podspec can't work?

Comment: No it won't. Given the Pod is the "manifest" that describes how the library will be integrated in a project. Without it, cocoapods wouldn't know how to integrate it. :)